# Handle error if identityserver discovery document is unreachable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have a .NET core WebAPI that uses two authentication schemes, the first one is AAD & the second one is identityserver4

```
    services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
    {
        authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        authOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer()//configured below for id4
    .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options)); 
    //AAD options
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
        AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
            };
        });

    //id4 options
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {

            options.Authority = "https://****/identity";
            options.Audience = Constants.Audience;
            options.MetadataAddress = "https://****/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration";

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });


    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme) //added both
            .Build();
    });
```

I am currently using this configuration in my startup.cs, When the identityserver4 host is down i am unable to authorize tokens issued by Azure active directory (the entire token verification goes down) & this is what i see in the logs

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://****/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://****/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): nodename nor servname provided, or not known
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
```

How does one handle such exceptions, i see an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11368) but i would assume there would be a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

First, **AddJWtBearer**, will complain if it can't reach the discovery endpoint when the first token arrives. One option that I have implemented in my system is to add a middleware that blocks incoming requests to reach it until it can make sure IdentityServer is reachable. It's not that hard to implement.

It can look like this:

[image]

If AddJwtBearer (via the ConfigurationManager) can't reach the discovery endpoint afterwards, it will reuse the existing configuration. It will refresh by default every 24 hours. If it fails, the retry period is 30 seconds.

Alternatively, that middleware could if it can't reach IdentitySerer, intead just "remove" the bearer token from the request. So that the request won't trigger AddJwtBearer.

Alternatively, you can download the source of AddJwtBearer from GitHub and then manually patch the authenticate method.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: so according to your comment, even if the token is issued by AAD and if the ID4 endpoint is down the `AddJwtBearer` middleware will still search for ID4 discovery document & the only way is to add a middleware that skips (?) the request from going through ID4 if it is down

Comment: I only have experience with using one JwtBearer handler and what I wanted to do in my setup was to wait for the IdentityServer to be available (like when we do a initial deploy when the API might start before IdentityServer). So in my case I wanted to wait and reply with 503 status code until the API is ready to accept traffic. Like a live vs readiness check.

Comment: An alternative to reduce your complexity internally is to only support one token internally and retrieve and accept Azure AD tokens through IdentityServer. So your system only depends on IdentityServer.

Comment: the only problem with that is, I am using AAD for primary accounts & i am trying to integrate 3rd party SSO which uses ID4 (not my instance).